# How does one display a legend on a pdf in matplotlib without it overlapping the x-axis of some graphs?

Tags: python, pdf, charts, matplotlib

I have been able to create a series of plots (6 x 3) in matplotlib and save them to a PDF. I would like a single legend per page. However, each legend overlasp the x-axis of the bottom center plot on each page. I tried changing the size of the image

```
fig = plot.figure(figsize=(8.27, 11.69), dpi=100)
```

but that did not work. I am using the following command to generate the legend:

```
plot.figlegend((p1[0], p2[0]), (assay1, assay2), loc='lower center', ncol=3, labelspacing=0)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make more space at the bottom of the figure by making the axes smaller either by using a 7 by 3 array of subplots or by each axis size directly.

```
fig = figure(figsize=(8.27, 11.69), dpi=100)

for i in range(1,19):
    subplot(7,3,i) # 7 by 3 subplot
    p1 = plot([1,2,3])
    p2 = plot([4,5,6])

figlegend((p1[0], p2[0]), ('assay1', 'assay2'), loc='lower center', ncol=3, labelspacing=0)
tight_layout()
savefig('test.png')
show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Molly. That is an option I had not considered but it also seems like a work around instead of an actual fix. The PDFs that are being created can be 100+ pages and this would make it even longer. That being said...if there is no real solution then I will have to do this.

Comment: It does seem like a work around. You could save some space by setting the size of each axis separately so that they fill up more of the page.